# cannot find symbol for QueryFactory - jena API

Tags: jena

```
import java.io.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDatatype.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.db.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.db.impl.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.compose.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.query.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelMaker.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.mem.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.mem.faster.*;

class Firstsparql{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Open the bloggers RDF graph from the filesystem
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("foaf.rdf"));

        // Create an empty in-memory model and populate it from the graph
        Model model = ModelFactory.createMemModelMaker().createModel();
        model.read(in,null); // null base URI, since model URIs are absolute
        in.close();

        // Create a new query
        String queryString =
        "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> " +
        "SELECT ?url " +
        "WHERE {" +
        "      ?contributor foaf:name \"Jon Foobar\" . " +
        "      ?contributor foaf:weblog ?url . " +
        "      }";

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

        // Execute the query and obtain results
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

        // Output query results
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);

        // Important – free up resources used running the query
        qe.close();
        }
}
```

Hi,  i have included jena.jar file in my classpath but still some of variables and methods are not recognised. ihope they are not defined in jena api..is there any other api i need to include.pls..let me..know. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CLASSPATH` needs to include all of the `.jar` files in the Jena lib directory, not just `jena.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from advise above, you can read about jena's architecture on https://jena.apache.org/documentation

Particularly, Jena's part for process SPARQL query called ARQ. ARQ.jar involves QueryFactory.